# Should one lain the trop while reciting Shiras Hayam during Pesukei D'zimra?

Tags: tefilla, trop-cantillation, pesukei-dezimra, shiras-hayam

Should one lain the trop while reciting Shiras Hayam during Pesukei D'zimra?

My siddur includes the trop for the Shiras Hayam, just as it does for the Shema.

With regards to the Shema I know of a source which discusses laining it during davening (see [Orach Chaim 61:24](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A1%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.9B.D7.93)).

If one should lain it, should one use the special tune we use on Shabbos Shira?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8425/what-does-cantillation-do-to-prayers-status

Comment: FWIW it's my minhag to do so for both. Also FWIW I've seen siddurim that include trop on any passuk that appears in the Siddur. So that's all of Pesukei D'Zimra, not just Az Yashir.

Comment: Fascinating that despite the 2 documented answers, the Shulchan Aruch, Kitzur, Aruch Hashulchan and Yalkut Yosef do not mention it. (Nor can I find it in the Mishna Berura)

Answer (score 16):

[סידור אוצר התפילות](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=57995&st=&pgnum=250) writes:

> וכן כתב של"ה שירת הים צריך לאמרה מעומד ובשמחה רבה כאלו אותה שעה יצא ממצרים, ובכוונה ובנגון הטעמים
>
> And so writes the *Shaloh*, *Shiras Hayam* must be said standing, and with great joy as if at that moment he one was leaving *mitzrayim*, with *kavana*, and with the tune of the *ta'amim*.

[סידור שפה ברורה](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43126&st=&pgnum=52&hilite=) (a German *siddur*) says:

> שירת הים צריך לאמרה מעומד בשמחה ובכוונה ובניגון הטעמים כמו בספר תורה
>
> *Shiras Hayam* must be said standing, with *kavana*, and with the tune of the *ta'amim* as in a *sefer torah*.

According to Siddur [Tefiloh Sefas Yisroel](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qoj5lwevr8y9n0d/Tefiloh-Sefas-Yisroel-v.1.16.pdf?dl=0) (pg. 37), this is indeed the German *Minhag*.

Answer (score 5):

Its brought down in Siddur Arizal to say Shiras Hayam with the trop.

[image]

Comment: What are you quoting?